# how to reorder endpoint rules using az cli cdn endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

how to reorder a CDN Endpoint rules using `az cli`

The documentation does not help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint/rule?view=azure-cli-latest

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `az cdn endpoint rule update` command available, you would have to call the [`Endpoints - Update` REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/endpoints/update?tabs=HTTP) directly with the updated payload and using the [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=bash%2Cbash2#rest-api-commands-az-rest) command instead.